# SOLR CSV processing error - missing required field

Tags: solr

When i try to index my CSV using this command:

curl http://:8983/solr/update/csv --data-binary @3QA_GetProductData.csv -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8'

I get this error:

```
<lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">400</int>
    <int name="QTime">47</int>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
    <str name="msg">[doc=100054-2-FLORALPRINT-1X] missing required field: ProdId</str>
    <int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
```

my 2-line CSV is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnXyYRhTvpj_dHg5LTdxM1Q1dE0zRkMyZ21CNTBtSUE&usp=sharing)

and the schema [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3XyYRhTvpj_aTdKSGdNSjZtbGc/edit?usp=sharing)
(sorry couldnt put inside here, lines too long)

Anything you can see?

thanks very much for any idea!

Lior

Comment: paste only the significant lines of your code. Also, are you using `ProdId` somewhere else by any chance? Would be really helpful seeing how you defined your prodid in `schema.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your definition of `ProdId` is this:

```
<field name="ProdId"  type="string" indexed="false" stored="false" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

As far as I can remember, Solr doesn't like a required field which is not `stored` nor `indexed`.

Also, I remember having weird issues when using `id` as a field name suffix.